# Validacion grupo de checkbox con javascript o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

buscando por la web no consigo encontrar la solucion, por eso pido ayuda, necesito validar un grupo de checkbox que se genera para cada fila de una tabla, lo que necesito es que se pueda seleccionar un check solo si el de la fila anterior se selecciono primero, es decir por ejemplo que de un error si quiero seleccionar el check de la fila 3, sin antes seleccionar el de la fila 2, esta es la tabla donde se generan los check:

```html
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
<thead>
  <tr> <!-- encabezado de tabla -->
    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#58acfa">
    <p style="color:#ffffff";><strong>TODAS LAS CUOTAS</strong></p>
    </td> 
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <th><center>Cuotas</center></th>
     <th><center>Importe</center></th>
  <th><center>Fecha de Vencimiento</center></th>                                   
  <th style="width: 20%;"><center>PAGAR</center></th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <?php
 if (count($cuentas) > 0) {
 if (is_array($cuentas)) {
  foreach ($cuentas as $cuenta):
   ?>
<tr>
  <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;"><center><?php echo element('cuotas', $cuenta); ?></center></td>
  <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;"><center><?php echo element('importe', $cuenta); ?></center></td>
  <?php $fechaVencimiento = element('fechaVencimiento', $cuenta); ?>
  <td style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;"><center><?php echo $fechaVencimiento;?></center></td>
  <td>
  <center>
<input type="checkbox">
  </center>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
endforeach;
}
}
  ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te pongo un ejemplillo que te podría resultar de utilidad:

```js
$('input').click(comprueba_anterior_seleccionado);

function comprueba_anterior_seleccionado () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
      if ($(this).parents('tr').prev('tr').find('input').prop('checked') == false) {
          alert('Anterior no clickado');
          $(this).prop('checked', false)
      }  
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox"> Prueba
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox"> Prueba
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox"> Prueba
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox"> Prueba
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que hago es moverme por **DOM** hasta llegar al **`tr`** padre del ckeckbox que se haya pulsado, después salto al anterior **`tr`** y busco un `input` ahí. Si encuentra que ese no está seleccionado deshago el que se quede marcado y listos.

Comment: es justo lo que estaba necesitando, te agradezco muchisimo mi amigo!

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo como esto:
pero debes usar un id incremental para cada checkbox

```js
    var el = (s) => document.querySelectorAll(s);
    check = el('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i <= check.length - 1; i++) {
        check[i].addEventListener("change", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let current = e.target.id.substring(1);
            if (current != 0) {
                let before = document.querySelector("#n" + (current - 1));
                if (before.checked == false) {
                    alert("debes darle checked al checkbox anterior");
                    e.target.checked = false;
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

```html
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="n0"  class="numero1"> Este es mi primer checkbox</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="n1" > <label for="cbox2">Este es mi segundo a clickear</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="n2" > Este es mi primer checkbox</label><br>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta Bryro, lo voy a tener encuenta, saludos!